# cant get media query to work

Tags: css, media-queries

I created a website that is mostly responsive, but it needed a little help when viewed on smaller screens.  I tried to add an @media query to the css page, but it doesn't seem to be making any difference.

I only added different style rules in my main css page, and did not add anything to my html.  I am confused on how media queries work exactly, so maybe that's my problem?

Here is my css

```css
/*Alt styles for smaller screens*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {

     div.price-area1 {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
     }

     div.price-area2 {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
     }

     div.price-area3 {
          width: 100%;
     }

     input.submit {
          width: 60%;
          margin-left: 20%;
     }

     nav {
          width: 100%;
     }

     nav ul li {
          position: relative;
          float: left;
          width: 50%;
          font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
          margin-bottom: 15px;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 24px;
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Where is this CSS placed compared to the rest of your CSS? Are these selectors as specific or more specific than your pre media query selectors? I'm guessing placement and/or specificty are the culprits here. Hard to give definitive answers with what you have provided.

Comment: After a bit more reading, I found that the css should go on the bottom of my stylesheet.  Apparently that was never mentioned in the other resources I was reading.  So, it's working now. Thanks

Comment: **#1** Read up on how the **cascade** works in *C*ascading *S*tyle *S*heets. This will answer where you should place your CSS selectors in your stylesheet. Looking into *CSS Specificity* wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand media queries is to read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en):

With that said, you may want to use a framework such as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) which is a great way to start a site. Otherwise you can use this template for media queries:

```css
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

This is a good starting point if you want to do it all yourself.

Comment: First, I love Bootstrap. Second, I would like to point out that one should _generally_ avoid getting tied up in targeting specific devices. **There's too many out there!** Rather one should find the _natural_ breakpoints in the design. When you resize the viewport you will know when a column, image, text, element, etc. needs to be moved, re-aligned, re-sized etc. If you do this then your design will be well suited for all screen sizes.